# Elixir piping output to an anonymous function

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex, ex

I'm currently learning elixir and i'm trying to print functions and their arity

```
print = fn ({function , arity}) ->
        IO.puts "#{function}/#{arity}" 
        end

Enum.__info__(:functions) |> Enum.each(print.())
```

this returns

```
** (BadArityError) #Function<0.60149952 in file:learn.exs> with arity 1 called with no arguments
    learn.exs:5: (file)
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ please use _formatter_ to format your code. `mix format` in a project, or the plugin to your editor of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is how you pass `print` to `Enum.each`. The variable `print` is already bound to a function. When you do `print.()` you're calling that function with no arguments and passing the result to `Enum.each`. What you want instead is to pass the `print` function itself as an argument to `Enum.each`. So:

```
Enum.__info__(:functions) |> Enum.each(print)
```

Comment: Please start the pipeline with a term as suggested by guidelines: `:functions |> Enum.__info__() |> Enum.each(print)` specifically when answering questions. Let’s teach newcomers good habits :)

Comment: The formatter doesn't enforce starting pipelines with a term, so IMO it's allowable. Furthermore, I think in this case it's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Paweł Obrok said, the reason this returns `BadArityError` is because `print.()` calls your `print` function with no arguments, but it expects a tuple as its argument.

That's actually masking the real problem - that you're calling the function instead of passing it as an argument. If you pass the `print.()` function call a tuple, thus resolving the `BadArityError`, you get the real error:

```
Enum.__info__(:functions) |> Enum.each(print.({:foo, :bar}))
```

> foo/bar
> ** (BadFunctionError) expected a function, got: :ok
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:769: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:769: Enum.each/2

The `print` function is executed, performing the `IO.puts "#{function}/#{arity}"` as you can see from the `foo/bar` output, then returns the result of `IO.puts/1`, which is`:ok`, and passes that as the second argument to `Enum.each`. That causes `BadFunctionError` because `Enum.each` expects a function as its second argument, but you gave the result of executing the function - the atom `:ok`.